# Raspberry Pi-4; pl2303_read_int_callback - usb_submit_urb failed with result -1

Tags: serial-port, usb, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to control 5V 4-Ch Relay Module http://www.icstation.com/icstation-micro-channel-relay-module-control-relay-module-icse012a-p-4012.html using Raspberry Pi-4, Model-B, 2GB RAM.

But sometimes I am observing "*pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303_read_int_callback - usb_submit_urb failed with result -1*" error and the Relay did not perform the required operation.

It would be good to know the root cause or the reason for this issue from the professional present here on this forum.
Any hint/clue would be really helpful and appreciated :) .

Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: there seem to be a defect in pl2303 driver caused by race or incorrect state after multiple connect/disconnect. Simply reload the pl2303 kernel model to workaround this issue when you get it.

Error '-1' (EPERM) in kernel USB stack is rare: I can find only one occurrence in urb submit path e.g.:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.99/source/drivers/usb/core/hcd.c#L1152

More to this, kernel documentation on `usb_kill_urb` says:

```
To cancel an URB synchronously, call usb_kill_urb():

void usb_kill_urb(struct urb *urb)
It does everything usb_unlink_urb() does, and in addition it waits until after
the URB has been returned and the completion handler has finished. It also marks
the URB as temporarily unusable, so that if the completion handler or anyone
else tries to resubmit it they will get a -EPERM error
```

So basically driver tries to submit INT IN URB after it got killed. Looking at the pl2303 driver code you can see only 2 places where INT IN URB is poisoned, e.g.:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.65/source/drivers/usb/serial/pl2303.c#L756
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.65/source/drivers/usb/serial/pl2303.c#L788

In both cases this happen on either close() or unsuccessful open() of USB serial device.

Proper fix would be to:

1. Check whether its open that fails on usb_serial_generic_open() function
2. Check whether INT IN URB killing is done properly and there's no race
3. Check if pl2303 code is aligned in general with recent USB Serial driver logic

Quick fix on the running system would be just
`rmmod pl2303 && modprobe pl2303`